# I have two points and a time, how do i find out the vector?

Tags: c++, math, vector, trigonometry, allegro5

I'm using allegro to.. Draw lines.
At some point on the line, an angle is chosen and a new line is drawn from that point for a fraction of the original length. Allegro uses a vector system to move points, i.e I will have a vector crtSpeed(0, -60) which updates the image 60 pixels distance on the Y. I am able to figure out the end point of the line doing some basic trig.

So basically, i have two points, and an amount of time it should take to travel between the two points. I do not know how to turn that information into an applicable vector.
To draw an example, i have the points
start(400, 300) and end(600, 200). Lets say it has ten seconds to draw this line- How does one derive the crtSpeed vector needed to make that line happen?

Comment: what's your framerate?

Comment: ah, currently 30, although can be changed in main. Does the framerate matter in this context?

Comment: Yes it does.  Its needed for unit conversions.  See my answer; hope it helps.

Comment: Unless you handle the framerate where you do the updates.  Basically be sure you know what units you expect the vector to be in.  Is it pixels/second or pixels/frame?  From what you describe I guessed pixels/frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given:

- start and destination coordinates (x and y, units of pixels)
- framerate (units of frames/second)
- duration (units of seconds)

You want:

- A speed vector (units of pixels/frame)

First you need your ∆x and ∆y (I'm writing this in C-like pseudocode):

```
dx = end.x - start.x
dy = end.y - start.y
```

You want to cover this distance over the duration.  That is, you want to move at ∆x/duration pixels/second.  But you want pixels/frame, so you divide by the framerate (1/(frames/second) = seconds/frame, pixels/second * seconds/frame = pixels/frame).

```
xSpeed = dx/duration/framerate
ySpeed = dy/duration/framerate
```